# JQuery - Переключение блоков при клике на другие блоки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 блока, вверху один активный (имеет класс `active`), другой нет. Есть 2 других блока ниже, со свойством `display:none`, но один, как можно догадаться, имеет класс, что он активный само собой отображается. Не могу разобраться в ситуации, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на верхний не активный блок, класс `active` переходил с одних блоков, верхнего и нижнего, на другие не активные. Пока что разобрался, как переключать классы при клике у верхних блоков, вместе с нижними не получается.

Код на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AShukilovich/ujfb3aL6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так :

В теги `title` можно добавить `data` атрибут, и в нем хранить какой блок ему соответствует, далее при клике вычитываем ето значение и делаем его активным, а остальные неактивными :

```js
$(".title").click(function(e) {
  $(".title").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  $('.block').removeClass('block-active');
  $($(this).attr('data-class')).addClass('block-active');
})
```

```css
.title {
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #eee;
}

.title.active {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  cursor: default;
}

.block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  display: none;
}

.block.block-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 title active" data-class=".block-1">Блок 1</div>
    <div class="col-6 title" data-class=".block-2">Блок 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container block block-1 block-active">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 text">Текст первого блока</div>
    <div class="col-4 text">Еще текст первого блока</div>
    <div class="col-4 text">И еще текст первого блока</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container block block-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 text">Текст второго блока</div>
    <div class="col-4 text">Еще текст второго блока</div>
    <div class="col-4 text">И еще текст второго блока</div>
  </div>
</div>
```